# Theme url in all plugin pages

Tags: php, plugin-development

I am developing a plugin. In my ranking.php, I have a form with the action called detailpage.php, which also resides with ranking.php. I want to add the activated themes header and footer to table_detail.php, but it is throwing errors (e.g "*Call to undefined function get_theme_root_uri()*")

How can I achieve this functionality (without the error)?

This is my ranking.php form:

```
 <form id="detail_form" method="POST" action="http://localhost/rating/wp-content/plugins/ranking/table_detail.php" target="_blank">
        <input type="text" name="detail_data" id="detail_data">
        <input type="submit">
    </form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By adding wp-blog-header.php in the files that reside outside wordpress you can use all the wordpress functionality. Thanks to the answer found [here](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/cant-include-wp-blog-headerphp-in-external-plugins-file-under-multisite/).